# Си | Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x7A8FFC60

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019

я не очень понимаю, почему не работает strcmp.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    char** Name;
    char* contrl;
    int i, k, midl, N, l, start, finish;
    char tmp[40];
    printf("введи длину списка: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    Name = (char**)malloc(N, sizeof(char*));
    printf("введи список: ");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", tmp);
        Name[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(tmp) + 2, sizeof(char));
        strcpy(Name[i], tmp);
    }
    printf("введи искомое название: ");
    scanf("%s", tmp);
    contrl = (char*)malloc(strlen(tmp) + 2, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(contrl, tmp);
    l = -1;
    start = 0;
    finish = N - 1;
    while ((l == -1) && (finish - start >= 0))
    {
        midl = (start + finish) / 2;
        k = strcmp(Name[i], contrl);
        if (k < 0)
        {
            finish = midl - 1;
        }
        if (k > 0)
        {
            start = midl + 1;
        }
        if (k = 0)
        {
            l = midl;
        }
    }
    printf("искомое название под номером: %d", l);
}
```

проблема в строчке `k = strcmp(Name[i], contrl);` выдаёт ошибку "Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x7A8FFC60 (ucrtbased.dll) в asd.c.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x8C001400". код пишу в vs 2019

Comment: У вас как минимум ошибка в использовании функции `malloc`, она принимает один аргумент, а вы передаете два. Либо используйте `calloc`, либо передавайте размер выделяемой памяти в виде произведения количества на размер типа

Comment: И если вы объявляете переменные заранее, то не забывайте их занулять. В цикле `while` у вас `i` уже имеет значение, равное длине введенного списка, т.к. после `for` ее значение не менялось. А значит в `strcmp` вы обращаетесь к индексу `Name`, которого нет. Либо объявляйте ее непосредственно в цикле (`for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)`), либо зануляйте перед `while`

Comment: У вас еще и поиск типа бинарного... Вы гарантируете, что введенные слова расположены отсортированными?

Answer (score 0):

Не работает, так как i вышло за пределы массива в предыдущем цикле, тут вместо i должна быть переменная midl. Однако и так поиск не будет работать, так как бинарный поиск работает только с отсортированными последовательностями.

Если Вам так важен бинарный поиск, я предложу такой вариант

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)
#define MAX_STR_LEN 40
#define READ_FORMAT "%" TOSTRING(MAX_STR_LEN) "s"

struct IndexName
{
    unsigned index;
    char name[MAX_STR_LEN];
};

typedef struct IndexName IndexName;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    printf("Len: ");

    int N;
    scanf("%d", &N);

    if (N < 0)
        return 0;
    
    printf("List: ");

    IndexName *names = (IndexName*)malloc(N * sizeof(IndexName));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        names[i].index = i;
        scanf_s(READ_FORMAT, names[i].name, MAX_STR_LEN);
    }

    char contrl[MAX_STR_LEN];
    printf("Pattern: ");
    scanf_s(READ_FORMAT, contrl, MAX_STR_LEN);
    
    for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; --j)
        {
            if (strcmp(names[j].name, names[j - 1].name) < 0)
            {
                IndexName tmp = names[j];
                names[j] = names[j - 1];
                names[j - 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    int l = -1;
    int start = 0;
    int finish = N - 1;

    while((l == -1) && (start <= finish))
    {
        int middle = (start + finish) / 2;
        int k = strcmp(names[middle].name, contrl);

        if (k > 0)
            finish = middle - 1;
        if (k < 0)
            start = middle + 1;
        if (k == 0)
            l = middle;
    }

    printf("Position: %d", l != -1 ? names[l].index : -1);
    return 0;
}
```

На будущее, старайтесь не использовать динамическую память без необходимости. В Вашем коде все строки ограничены размером tmp, так почему бы не использовать это?